# problems with FindByLocationWithin

Tags: spring, mongodb

I'm trying to query a mongo repository to return data that is within a specified geo circle. I'm using the following code:

```
Page<Img> findByLocationWithin(Circle circle, Pageable pageable);
```

and then in my controller I'm using:

```
Distance distance = new Distance(7.5, Metrics.MILES);
Circle circle = new Circle(location, distance);
Page<Img> results = imgRepository.findByLocationWithin(circle, pageable);
```

However it definitely doesn't use a radius of 7.5 miles as if I create the circle a few hundred metres away from where the data is located, it returns nothing. I've checked the logs in mongo and it says that the following code is being performed:

```
"location" : {
    "$within" : {
        "$center" : [
                        [
                            30.198,
                            -1.695
                        ],
                        0.0018924144710663706
                    ]
                }
            }
```

This means it's not using `$geoWithin` or `$centerSphere`. How can I fix these problems?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `spring` and `Couchbase`... but the query is not the problem... Because `Spring` convert the distance in the geometric values.
In my case I also returned `null`, but my problem was solved, in the model class, the attribute that specifies the coordinate [x, y] must be of type Library Point `org.springframework.data.geo.Point;`

```
package com.webServices.rutas.model;

import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.id.GeneratedValue;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.id.GenerationStrategy;
import org.springframework.data.geo.Point;

import com.couchbase.client.java.repository.annotation.Field;
import com.couchbase.client.java.repository.annotation.Id;

public class Parada {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.UNIQUE)
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String type;
    @Field
    private String nombre;
    @Field
    private String urlFoto;
    @Field
    private Point coordenada;
    public Parada(String nombre, String urlFoto, Point coordenada) {
        super();
        this.type = "parada";
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.urlFoto = urlFoto;
        this.coordenada = coordenada;
    }
    public Parada() {
        super();
        this.type = "parada";
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getUrlFoto() {
        return urlFoto;
    }
    public void setUrlFoto(String urlFoto) {
        this.urlFoto = urlFoto;
    }
    public Point getCoordenada() {
        return coordenada;
    }
    public void setCoordenada(Point coordenada) {
        this.coordenada = coordenada;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parada [id=" + id + ", type=" + type + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", urlFoto=" + urlFoto + ", coordenada="
                + coordenada + "]";
    }
}
```

In the service:

```
public Iterable<Parada> getParadasCercanasRadio(Punto punto){
        Point cuadro = new Point(-2.2,-80.9);
        Circle circle = new Circle(cuadro,new Distance(300000, Metrics.KILOMETERS));
        return paradaRepository.findByCoordenadaWithin(circle);
}
```

In the Repository:

```
@Dimensional(designDocument = "paradas", spatialViewName = "paradas")
Iterable<Parada> findByCoordenadaWithin(Circle p);
```

P.D. Sorry for my English.